# CRIO runtime spec for OCI v1alpha1 compliance

Tags: lxc, runc, cri-o

devs, where can I find the spec for a cri-o runtime cmdline interface to be fully [OCI v1alpha1](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-tools/blob/master/docs/command-line-interface.md) compliant?

> CRI-O supports any OCI compatible runtime. We test with runc and Clear Containers today.

But while playing around with `crictl` I noticed that cri-o uses runc commands and flags
that are nowhere defined within the [OCI Runtime Command Line Interface version 1.0.1](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-tools/blob/master/docs/command-line-interface.md) e.g the `exec` command. I tried to get the [LXC runtime for cri-o](https://github.com/lxc/crio-lxc) working and noticed that `exec` is missing from the cmdline.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is an issue with LXC. The issue with OCI is we rely on commands matching up with the way that runc works.